# Make right half of website different style in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a website that one half is white and the other half it dark gray. I am using a wrapper now that gives it a defined width and centers it like this: `margin: 0px auto 0px auto;`.

If you look at the website here (link removed), you will see the dark bar has stopped and is confined to that width. What would be my best bet in order to achieve this?

You can look at my stylesheet here (link removed).

Thanks in advance!
Coulton

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking.  Doesn't the link http://myflashpics.com/v2/ already show the effect you wish to achieve?  Isn't that your site?

Comment: This IS my site. I want the DARK GRAY background to extend all the way to the right, not cut off and show white. If that makes sense.. In essence, I want one half to be WHITE and one half to be DARK GRAY.

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help, Coulton.  I see that you've edited the question and removed the links to your site.  Can you add enough context (pertinent code) back into this question so that this question makes sense?  The best kind of questions on Stackoverflow are those that will help future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend the dark gray background from div.right_bar all the way to the right side of the screen, you can remove the width from the parent element div.wrapper.  For example:

```
.wrapper { width: 100%; }
```

When the width on div.wrapper is specified, it doesn't fill all of the horizontal space of the page, and the white from the body element shows through.

Comment: Thanks! Did quite a bit of rearranging and it works.. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Done this a few times.

Create a LOOOONG horizontal line of that grey color as an image. Make it like 1200px wide (1px in height). Then in CSS set it as the body background with something like this:

```
background:url("urlToLongHorizontalLine.png") repeat-y scroll 52% 0 transparent;
```

the 52% will position it so that it only begins at about the center (you may have to adjust it slightly), and repeat-y will tile it vertically.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thought about doing that. Realy don't want to complicate things. Changed COLUMNS to % and put divs with content in them.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps inside your main div, create two more divs - left and right. Then in CSS define their size/position, etc.

Comment: Thought about doing that. But how am I going to do that? I have a LEFT_BAR that is 400px and RIGHT_BAR that is 500px. Please post some code! Thanks, Coulton